# Can I use my computer's Wi-Fi connection with the DeSmuME core in OpenEmu?

Tags: emulation, nintendo-ds, desmume

I'm using the emulator-conglomerating application OpenEmu, and to emulate the Nintendo DS it uses the DeSmuME core. I've been able to find tutorials online to use the computer's Wi-Fi connection with the standalone DeSmuME application, but is there any way to accomplish the same within OpenEmu?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I know that official DeSmuME builds do not support wifi, but there are builds you can download that have it enabled. [More information.](http://linkbun.ch/02es5)

Comment: Ah, I see, I hadn't realized those were instructions for non-official builds. That information makes it highly unlikely that it would be possible to enable it in Open Emu until it is officially supported, as the cores are custom-built for the program. Should this question be closed, then?

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to want the DSEMU core I would suggest using it itself. Unless you can find a video saying that It is for OpenEmu because certain setup steps would be required.